# Is it safe to use 1/8 watt resistors in this circuit?

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, resistance

If I have the following circuit is it safe to use 1/8 watt resistors?

My details are as follows :

1. 5V at 800mA == it is an old phone charger! I assume the voltage is constant but the current will depend on the load ( I don't know how to prove this, just am assuming this to be the typical behaviour of phone chargers? ) The charger itself is a Nokia AC-15X - https://www.amazon.co.uk/Nokia-AC-15X-Compact-Travel-Charger-BLACK/dp/B004I647J2
2. The resistors are rated at 1/8 watt.
3. The led draws I think 50mA.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftj89g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that `P=IV`, so if this is the case,

`P=0.050A x 5V == 250mW` - suggesting that this is over the `0.125` watt rating of my resistors.

If this is the case, can you recommend a decent set mixed value 5 watt resistors (just so I am safe) -- seems to be loads of little selections on 1/8 or 1/4 watt but I cannot find a nice range on higher power ranges!

Comment: 5W resistors tend to be expensive, which is why you don't see too many sets of them.

Comment: Power is measured in Watts, so `P=0.050A x 5V == 250mA` is incorrect, it would be milliWatts, or  `P=0.050A x 5V == 0.250W`. As 0.25W is 2x 0.125W that resistor is going to get very hot, and likely fail. A good rule of thumb is to use resistors rated for 2x the power. So 0.5W resistor should be okay. The situation is slight less than you think as the LED will 'use' (drop) datasheet says 2V, so the current is (5-2)V/100ohms, hence Power = 0.03A * 3V = 0.09W. That is a bit too close, but 0.25W would be fine.

Comment: Ok what is a good source for a 1/4 watt set of resistors then? Seems I would be safer using them.

Answer (score 5):

> P=0.050A x 5V == 250mA

No, the power only takes the voltage *dropped* into consideration. You need to reduce the supply voltage by the forward voltage of the LED to determine the voltage dropped across the resistor.

But if we assume a forward voltage of 1.2V (typical of an IR LED, one of the few that would use 50mA) then we get a power dissipation of 190mW. So either move up to a 1/4W resistor or use two 1/8W resistors in parallel.

Comment: So how do I know the 'forward voltage' to work out the voltage drop?

Comment: You read the datasheet of the LED.

Comment: and how does putting 2 1/8 resistors in parallel somehow allow a greater maxium power rating!?

Comment: so does forward voltage mean, the amount of voltage it drops the source by? So if I measured the voltage after the LED, it would be 3.8V!? Doesnt seem right?

Comment: Using two resistors means that each conducts half the current. *Every* part in the circuit drops voltage, not just the LED.

Comment: @RenegadeAndy The resistors have to be double the value (200 ohms in parallel with 200 ohms) so each one only sees half the dissipation. If you only have 100 ohm resistors you can put four in series-parallel to get a 100 ohm 0.5W resistor.

Answer (score 2):

Don't guess. confirm or show parts and ask

> "The led draws I think 50mA"

- 5mm 20mA rated for Red/Yellow @2.2V = 44mW

  - thus R = (5-2.2V)/20mA= 140 Ohms and 3.8V*20mA = 74mW dissipated in R
  - so 1/8th W is ok
- 5mm 20mA rated for Blue/White @3.2V = 64mW

  - thus R= (5-3.2V)/20mA= 90 Ohms
  - and 2.8V*20mA = 56mW dissipated in R
  - so ok.

If really 50mA rated or a 350mW rated LED then R will need bigger W ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Power is measured in Watts, so `P=0.050A x 5V == 250mA` is incorrect.

It would be milliWatts, or  `P=0.050A x 5V == 0.250W`.

As 0.25W is 2x 0.125W that resistor would get very hot, and likely fail. A good rule of thumb is to use resistors rated for 2x the power.

The actual power dissipation in this situation is less than you think.
That LED will 'use' (drop voltage) according to its [datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTL-307EE.pdf) 2V, so there is only (5V-2V) = 3V across the rest of the circuit, in this case the 100 ohm resistor.

So the current is V/=I,  (5-2)V/100ohms = 0.03A, hence
Power = 0.03A * 3V = 0.09W.

That is a bit close for 0.125W resistor, but 0.25W would be fine.

Or two 200ohm 0.125 resistors in parallel, or, if 100ohm 0.125W is all you have got, 4 resistors, two parallel pairs of two in series.

Edit:
A resistor doesn't draw current. There is 5V across the resistor and LED, and that 5V is *all* driving the current.

Looking at the [LTL-307EE datasheet](http://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTL-307EE.pdf), practically, the LED will not conduct until it has 1.6V across it (Fig 2 in the datasheet); with a voltage below this, it looks like a large resistor, 1000's of ohm or much more.

At 2.0V it will conduct 20mA. As the voltage increases it will 'conduct like crazy', needing little more voltage (data sheet suggests about 2.6V) to drive so much current that it will be destroyed. So for voltages above about 2V, the circuit needs something to limit the current, and so stop the LED from destroying itself. That is what the resistor is doing.

However, all of the power, P=VI, 3v*0.03a = 0.9W, is being converted to heat by the resistor. So the power rating of the resistor is statement of how much power it can convert to heat. But it's temperature will rise the closer to its power rating it must dissipate. So generally a resistor with 2x the required power rating is used.

Comment: So this 'used voltage' is the 'voltage drop'? I find this in the datasheet. Does this mean only 3V runs around the rest of my circuit after the LED? Or does it simply mean, the resistor only draws some of the Voltage its being supplied - because it is given 5v!

Comment: @RenegadeAndy You might want to look up "Kirchhoff's circuit laws tutorials" and have a bit of a study. It will stand you in good stead to understand them.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the specs of the led listed in your schematic at [digikey](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Lite-On%20PDFs/LTL-307EE.pdf).

All other answers explain quite in detail how to calculate the power dissipation of all the circuit, so I will be very brief here.

- LED forward voltage: 2V, max 2.6V
- Continuous forward current: 30mA
- Peak forward current (if you are doing some fancy PWM or the like) 120mA

Taking your 5V supply, lets proceed to calculate your resistor. We want 30mA, at 5V, with a forward voltage of 2V. So the voltage at the resistor will be 3V, meaning that it has to be **100Ω** to obtain the desired 30mA (Just as you have placed it).

If your particular LED would have a higher forward voltage, the resistor will limit the current below the recommended (by the manufacturer) 30mA.

And now to your question. Using Joules equation (P = I²·R): 
**P = (30mA)²·100Ω = 90mW.**
Which is less than 125mW.

Therefore, **your circuit will be just fine** (as long as the ambient temperature in which your device operates is [below 70ºC as recommended in this thread](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/261198/124842)).